# Scope $watch between controller and directive not working only after minification

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I have a controller/view with a directive in it. That directive changes a variable that the controller scope is watching. This works perfectly until I minify everything. Once minified, there's no error but the watch handler doesn't fire any more.

My app is compiled by `grunt` using `yeoman` angular generator. After a lot of work it's building everything correctly (via `grunt serve:dist`). Apart from the fact the watch function handler isn't working, the rest of the app is fine. During development, everything works perfectly.

I've pretty sure all my dependancies are declared to avoid any minification problems. I'm also using `ngAnnotate` to clean up any I've missed. What could be the problem?

Here's a simplified example:

Controller:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

    MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', ...];

    function MyCtrl($scope, ...) {
        $scope.color = null;

        $scope.$watch('color', function(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('Color changed');
        });
    };
})();
```

View:

```
<mydirective color="color"></mydirective>
```

Directive:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('mydirective', mydirective);

    function mydirective() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                color: '=color'
            },
            templateUrl: 'directive.html',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs, form) {
                $scope.clickHandler = function(val) {
                    $scope.color = val;
                };
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Directive template:

```
<button ng-click="clickHandler('blue')"></button>
```

Comment: This is a shot in the dark but can you try changing $scope to scope in the directive. I read somewhere that in the directive you should use scope instead of $scope because it is not a dependancy injection.

Comment: Good suggestion actually, but unfortunately it doesn't make a difference. Having turned off `uglify` the problem persists, so it seems it's actually a general build problem. I have a feeling it might be to do with the template cache. I'll have to do more investigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, this ended up being an issue with the minification of my third-party bower components (in particular I think it was `jquery-ui` and `ui-date`). Nothing to do with what I originally thought but someone might end up here with the same symptoms. I ended up having to go back through each step of my grunt file manually until it worked (which was when I removed the extra unused dependancies in `vendor.js`)

Comment: I have the same problem, but is there any easy to to find  extra unused dependencies?